# Azure Rule engine File extension with json file

Tags: azure, rule-engine, azure-cdn

I am trying to create a rule engine in a cdn endpoint. like this:

[image]

But using a Json file (The result in the image has been achieved manually but now i want to automate this).

So far I got this:

```
"deliveryPolicy": {
          "description": "Rewrite and Redirect",
          "rules": [
                {
                  "name" :  "UrlFileExtension",
                  "order": 2,
                  "conditions": [
                    {
                      "name": "UrlFileExtension",
                      "parameters": {
                          "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.UrlFileExtensionMatchConditionParameters",
                          "Extension": 0,
                          "operator": "LessThanOrEqual",
                          "matchValues": [0]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "name": "UrlRewrite",
                      "parameters": {
                        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.DeliveryRuleUrlRewriteActionParameters",
                        "sourcePattern": "/",
                        "destination": "/index.html",
                        "preserveUnmatchedPath": false
                      }
                    }
                  ]
              },
```

The `action` works just fine, but the `urlfileextention`I cant get it to work, it does not recognize the odata.type either.

Please any hint ot suggestion how to fix the condition?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with this odata.type for the condition

`"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.DeliveryRuleUrlFileExtensionMatchConditionParameters",`

instead of

`"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.UrlFileExtensionMatchConditionParameters",`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cdn/azure.mgmt.cdn.models.urlfileextensionmatchconditionparameters?view=azure-python

(I'm aware the documentation says Python, I could not find better, but it could be your solution)